# Why are my Google Maps API requests populating so slowly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a script in python3 (using Jupyter notebook) that queries the coordinates of each address using Google Maps Geocoding API. The limit imposed by Google is 50 requests per second, but my code is running far slower (maybe 20 minutes to process 1000 lines).

I am using the python requests library for the api calling, and using pandas to perform the data transformations (i.e. parsing the json output into the desired format). I am feeding my inputs in batches to avoid losing all my  outputs in the case of unexpected exceptions.

My question is, why does each iteration take so long?! I am pretty new to this, so it's hard for me to identify what's slowing me down.

Code snippet:

```
def populate_coordinates(list_of_addresses, api = api_key):
    filled_table = pd.DataFrame({"Pickup address": [],
                                 "Status": [],
                                 #"Postal": [],
                                 "Formatted address": [],
                                 "Lat": [],
                                 "Long": [],
                                 "Location type": []})
    count = 0
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings() 
    for address in list_of_addresses:
        data = {"address": address,
                "key": api,
                "region": "us"}
        response = requests.get(endpoint, params = data, verify = False)
        response_json = response.json()
        if response_json["status"] == "OK":
            #address_comp = pd.DataFrame(response_json["results"][0]["address_components"])
            #postal = address_comp[address_comp["types"]=="postal_code"]["long_name"][0]
            fmt_add = response_json["results"][0]["formatted_address"]
            lat = response_json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
            long = response_json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
            loc_type =  response_json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location_type"]

            filled_table = filled_table.append({"Pickup address": address,
                                                "Status": response_json["status"],
                                                #"Postal": postal,
                                                "Formatted address": fmt_add,
                                                "Lat": lat,
                                                "Long": long,
                                                "Location type": loc_type}, ignore_index = True)
        else:
            filled_table = filled_table.append({"Pickup address": address,
                                                "Status": response_json["status"],
                                                #"Postal": None,
                                                "Formatted address": None,
                                                "Lat": None,
                                                "Long": None,
                                                "Location type": None }, ignore_index = True)
        count+=1
        print ("Processing: {} of {} addresses".format(count, len(list_of_addresses)))
    return filled_table
```

And here's the batching part (if that's relevant):

```
batch_sz = 2000
num_batch = 0
num_entries = 0

results = pd.DataFrame({"Pickup address": [],
                        "Status": [],
                        "Formatted address": [],
                        "Lat": [],
                        "Long": [],
                        "Location type": []})
while num_entries<len(addresses):
    num_batch+=1
    batch_complete = populate_coordinates(addresses[num_entries:num_entries+batch_sz])
    num_entries+=batch_sz
    results = pd.concat([results, batch_complete], sort = False)
```

Any other tips / recommendations are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It may take long time because when you request a data with any API method you make an HTTP request to retrieve a response in JSON format but of course this is not the reason. I've also tried a few times Google Map API and I think trying that much requests may things get slower.Because sometimes this kinda sites gives you limited request during a constrained time.

Also parsing processes may take time.

Comment: Ah yes, I was afraid it might be the parsing as I have found pandas to be pretty slow at certain tasks. Thanks for the suggestions!